# Find, for example, a commutative ring $R$ where $2:= 1+ 1$ is invertible and $x^2$ has more than two roots in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Here's my attempt. Let $x=e_1 + e_2$. Notice, $x^2=(e_1^2+e_2^2)=e_1^2+e_2^2+2e_1e_2=e_1+e_2+2e_1e_2=x+2e_1e_2$. So, $x^2-x=2e_1e_2$. We need to find the roots for $x^2-x$ i.e $2e_1e_2=0$. Consider $x=0+e_2=e_1+0$, $x=e_1+e_2$ and $x=0+0$ have the values $e_1,e_2$ that is either zero are 1 because $x(x-1)=0$. But we  just shown $x=e_2$ and $x=e_1$, meaning its a boolean ring since all x are idempotent. So every element x from the boolean ring coincides with it additive inverse (i.e $x+x=0$). We need to find such ring which gives $x+x=2x=0$. But notice, we can find infinite roots if $x^2-x\in Z_{2}[x]$, the integer mods 2 polynomials.

Comment: This is somewhat unclear. You're looking for a ring $R$ such that $2\in R$ is invertible, and $x^2 \in R[x]$ has more than two roots, yes?

Comment: I'm looking for exactly what you just stated.

Comment: Please include your question in your post. The post doesn't start on the subject line. Right now, it starts where it says "Here's my attempt". Attempt at what? Oh, wait, we need to go read the *envelope of the letter* to know what you are talking about.

Comment: Just pick $\mathbb Q[x,y]/(x^2, y^2)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $R= \mathbb{Z}/(9\mathbb{Z})$. It's easy to see $2\in R$ is invertible and that $x^2\in R[x]$ has three roots.

Comment: So, 5*2=10 (mod 9) = 1, and x has three roots which are 0^2, 3^2, and 9^2?

Comment: The third root is $6 \neq 9 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$.

Comment: At first I thought it was asking for multiple _square roots_ of $x^2\in R$ (more than $\pm x$), not _polynomial roots_ of $x^2\in R[x]$. Of course polynomial roots of $x^2$ are the same as square roots of $0^2$, but it's a bit more interesting if we require $x\in R$ to be invertible. One example is $1^2\equiv4^2\equiv11^2\equiv14^2\bmod15$.